# How to match Apple IAP Subscription updates with transactions from flutter_inapp_purchase?

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, storekit, flutter-in-app-purchase

I used flutter_inapp_purchase (5.1.2) to set up IAP subscription purchases for iOS.
Now, I'd like to receive subscription updates (ie. user cancelled subscription). I'm setting up a Firebase cloud function to receive the IAP notifications from Apple.
However, how do I link these with the user in my Firebase database to update their premium status?
What is the standard best practice for how to link these notifications to users in my syste?

Options:

- unique_vendor_identifier = based on device ID. However, I read some articles that said this changed over time, which doesn't seem like
  the best way to match up a user
- original_transaction_id = match to the original subscription transaction using the original transaction id field passed over on
  the IAP notification from Apple. However, I see edge cases where this
  wouldn't work, for example if a user unsubscribes and the re-instates
  their subscription--would the original_transaction_id be preserved?
  Maybe this would work for my use case.

Does anyone have any other ideas for elements that could be preserved to match up the user with the right notifications?

Separately, is app_account_token from IAP notifications the same thing as purchaseToken in the flutter_inapp_purchase library and is this preserved at all in a way that could be useful for this purpose?